# Javascript - Create nested object from array based on edge conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Recursion kills me every time.

I have the following array:

```
fooArray: Foo[] = 
[
  { foo: "a", indent: 0 },
  { foo: "b", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "c", indent: 2 },
  { foo: "d", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "e", indent: 2 },
  { foo: "f", indent: 2 },
  { foo: "g", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "h", indent: 0 },
]
```

I would like to map this to a different type of object (TS), and nest the objects based on their indent values as such:

```
interface Bar {
  foo: string,
  bar?: Bar[]
}

barArray: Bar[] = 
[
  { 
    foo: "a", 
    bar: [
      { foo: "b",
        bar: [{ foo: "c" }],
      { foo: "d",
        bar: [
          { foo: "e" }, 
          { foo: "f"}
        ] 
      },
      {
        foo: "g"
      }
    ]
  },
  { foo: "h" }
]
```

I've been trying to mess with reducers but needing to determine the level of recursion based on neighboring array members is really wracking my brain. If anyone has any thought it would be much appreciated!

Comment: We can get pretty close using array methods. Will it always be the "last" item of an indent level to get the `bar` property (e.g. `foo: a, bar…` and `foo: c, bar…`). All of your items only increase or decrease by a maximum of one indent at a time. Will it ever jump more than one indent (1 ➞ 3 ➞ 5, etc.)?

Comment: It should only jump one at a time. If it doesn't I'll ensure the edge condition is only whether the indent is greater that results in adding bar.

And no, there could be multiple bars within a list of foos. I'll try to add a bit more to clarify the original question.

I'm getting closer to the solution with a recursive reducer along with array.splice. I'll post what I have when I get close.

Comment: Yes, please add that. I'm leaving my half-finished answer to come back to later.

Answer (score 0):

My solution here is entirely a work in progress, so please do not test or try it just yet. I have to step away for a while and wanted to leave this here to come back to later:

```js
let fooArray = [
  { foo: "a", indent: 0 },
  { foo: "b", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "c", indent: 2 },
  { foo: "d", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "e", indent: 2 },
  { foo: "e1", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "e2", indent: 0 },
  { foo: "e3", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "f", indent: 2 },
  { foo: "g", indent: 1 },
  { foo: "h", indent: 0 },
];

// let barArray = fooArray.slice().flatMap((e,i,a) => i ? null : Array(a.filter(f => !f.indent).length).fill().map((f,j,b) => a.splice(0,Math.max(a.slice(1).findIndex(g => g.indent === 0)+1,1))));

// WIP // let barArray = fooArray.slice().flatMap((e,i,a) => i ? null : Array(a.filter(f => !f.indent).length).fill().map((f,j,b) => a.splice(0,Math.max(a.slice(1).findIndex(g => g.indent === 0)+1,1)))).map(e => e.map((f,i,a) => a[i+1]?.indent > f.indent ? { foo: f.foo, bar: a.splice(i+1,i+2) } : f).filter(f => f));

// WIP #2 // let barArray = fooArray.slice().map(e=>({...e})).flatMap((e,i,a) => i ? null : Array(a.filter(f => !f.indent).length).fill().map((f,j,b) => a.splice(0,Math.max(a.slice(1).findIndex(g => g.indent === 0)+1,1)))).map(e => e.reverse().map((f,i,a) => /*console.log(`a[i]: ${JSON.stringify(a[i])}\nf: ${JSON.stringify(f)}`) ||*/ a[i+1]?.indent < f.indent ? (a[i+1].bar = [{foo:f.foo}], a.splice(i,i+1)) : {foo:f.foo}).filter(f=>f).reverse());

// WIP #3 // let barArray = fooArray.slice().map(e=>({...e})).flatMap((_,i,a) => i ? null : Array(a.filter(e => !e.indent).length).fill().map(e => a.splice(0,Math.max(a.slice(1).findIndex(f => f.indent === 0)+1,1)))).map(e => e.length > 1 ? e.flatMap((_,i) => i ? null : Array(e.filter(e => !e.indent).length).fill().map(f => e.splice(0,Math.max(e.slice(1).findIndex(g => g.indent === 0)+1,1)))) : e);

// simple get object // let barArray = fooArray.slice().map(e=>({...e})).flatMap((_,i,a) => i ? null : Array(a.filter(e => !e.indent).length).fill().map(e => a.splice(0,Math.max(a.slice(1).findIndex(f => f.indent === 0)+1,1))));

// NEW WIP

fooArray.slice().map(e=>({...e})).flatMap((_,i,a) => i ? null : Array(a.filter(e => !e.indent).length).fill().map(e => a.splice(0,Math.max(a.slice(1).findIndex(f => f.indent === 0)+1,1)))).map(e => e.length > 1 ? { foo: e[0].foo, bar: e.slice(1) } : e[0])
.map(a => a.bar ? 
    ((a.bar = a.bar.reverse().flatMap((e,i) => 
        a.bar.findIndex((f,j) => j > i && e.indent !== f.indent) !== -1 ? 
            (a.bar.find((f,j) => j > i && e.indent !== f.indent).indent > e.indent ? e : (a.bar.find((f,j) => j > i && e.indent !== f.indent).bar = a.bar.splice(i,a.bar.findIndex((f,j) => j > i && e.indent !== f.indent))))
            : e
    ).reverse()), a)
    : a
)

console.log(barArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I might try to make mine a bit more solid by using some of your ideas here. I ended up just writing a for loop that would loop indent times and set the current "node" to the last bar of the array. Works as long as indent only increments by 1.

Comment: @jmroon sweet! Could you post the final result here for me to test with?

Comment: Sure I’ll post it tomorrow. I need to Foobarise it. :p It’s not particularly elegant, but it works.